# RAII state management

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, raii

I need to change a state. Then do stuff. Then reset the state back to what it was - e.g:

```
auto oldActivationOrder = mdiArea->activationOrder();
mdiArea->setActivationOrder( QMdiArea::StackingOrder );
mdiArea->cascadeSubWindows();
mdiArea->setActivationOrder( oldActivationOrder );
```

How do I do this in a RAII way?
(c++ 11 and/or 14)

Edit: Thanks for all the answers.

There are several suggestions to create a custom class for handling the state change (BoBTFish, mindriot, Mattias Johansson). This solution seems good and clear. However I think it is a drawback that it increases the line count from 4 to 20+. If used a lot this would bloat the code. Also it seems that some locality is lost by having a separate class.

Ami Tavory suggests using std::unique_ptr. This does not have the code bloat issue and maintains locality. However, as Ami also indicates, it may not be the most readable solution.

sp2danny suggests a generalized state-change class that can be reused. This avoids code bloat provided that it can replace several custom classes. I'm going to accept this answer - but I guess the right approach really depends on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a generic template:

```
template< typename Obj, typename Getter, typename Setter , typename StateType >
class ScopedStateChangeType
{
public:
    ScopedStateChangeType( Obj& o, Getter g, Setter s, const StateType& state )
        : o(o), s(s)
    {
        oldstate = (o.*g)();
        (o.*s)(state);
    }
    Obj* operator -> () { return &o; }
    ~ScopedStateChangeType()
    {
        (o.*s)(oldstate);
    }

private:
    Obj& o;
    Setter s;
    StateType oldstate;
};

template< typename Obj, typename Getter, typename Setter , typename StateType >
auto MakeScopedStateChanger( Obj& o, Getter g, Setter s, StateType state )
     -> ScopedStateChangeType<Obj,Getter,Setter,StateType>
{
    return { o, g, s, state };
}
```

use it like:

```
QMdiArea mdiArea;

{
    auto ref = MakeScopedStateChanger(
        mdiArea, &QMdiArea::activationOrder, &QMdiArea::setActivationOrder,
        QMdiArea::StackingOrder );
    ref->cascadeSubWindows();
}
```

maybe it's worth it if you use this pattern often

Answer (score 7):

RAII: **R**esource **A**cquisition **I**s **I**nitialisation.

Which also implies that Resource Release Is Destruction, although I've never seen people talk about RRID, even though that's the more useful side of it. (Perhaps that should be Termination, or Finalisation?)

The point is, you do some work in the constructor of an object, and effectively reverse it in the destructor. This means that the cleanup is carried out no matter how you exit the scope: multiple `return`s, multiple `break`s, throw an exception, ... (even `goto`!)

```
class ScopedActivationOrderChange {
    QMdiArea&             area_;     // the object to operate on
    QMdiArea::WindowOrder oldOrder_; // save the old state

  public:
    ScopedActivationOrderChange(QMdiArea& area, ActivationOrder newOrder)
        : area_(area)
        , oldOrder_(area_.activationOrder()) // save old state
    {
        area_.setActivationOrder(newOrder); // set new state
    }

    ~ScopedActivationOrderChange()
    {
        area_.setActivationOrder(oldOrder_); // reset to old state
    }
};

// ...

{ // <-- new scope, just to establish lifetime of the change
    ScopedActivationOrderChange orderChange{*mdiArea, QMdiArea::StackingOrder};
    mdiArea->cascadeSubWindows();
} // <-- end of scope, change is reversed
```

The Standard Library doesn't provide any general facility for this. It does provide some for more specific uses, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for deleting dynamically allocated objects, which can in some cases be used for other things, though it's a bit ugly. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) can be seen as a RAII class for dynamic arrays, providing some other management facilities also, but this one is less easily abused for other purposes.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the most succinct way (albeit possibly not the most readable) of implementing the [scoped guard pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Scope_Guard) is to use a [`std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter](https://philwrightdev.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/providing-a-custom-deleter-to-stdunique_ptr/):

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>


int main()
{
    void *p, *q;                                                                                                                                                                                         
    auto reverser = [&p, &q](char *){std::swap(p, q);};
    /* This guard doesn't really release memory - 
        it just calls the lambda at exit. */
    auto guard = std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(reverser)>{nullptr, reverser};
    std::swap(p, q);
}
```

Comment: I don't think the swap applies to my situation - but I suppose I can write the setActivationOrder( oldActivation ) in the reverser lambda.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
class SetActivationOrder
{
public:
  SetActivationOrder(QMdiArea *mdiArea, QMdiArea::WindowOrder order)
    : m_mdiArea(mdiArea),
      m_oldActivationOrder(mdiArea->activationOrder())
  {
    m_mdiArea->setActivationOrder(order);
  }

  ~SetActivationOrder()
  {
    m_mdiArea->setActivationOrder(m_oldActivationOrder)
  }

private:
  QMdiArea *m_mdiArea;
  QMdiArea::WindowOrder m_oldActivationOrder;
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
{
  // This sets the order:
  SetActivationOrder sao(mdiArea, QMdiArea::StackingOrder);
  mdiArea->cascadeSubWindows();
  // Destructor is called at end of scope and sets the old order
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With RAII (Resource Allocation Is Initialization) you would create an instance of a storage class in the local scope (i.e. on the stack). You pass the state you want to store into the constructor of the storage object and make sure that the destructor of the storage object restores the state again. Because C++ guarantees that the destructor of an object on the local scope will be automatically called for you when the object goes out of scope, also if an exception is thrown, you don't have to worry about remembering to restore the state again.

I would write the class like this:

```
class ActivationOrderState
{
public:
    ActivationOrderState(QMdiArea& area)
        : m_area(area)
    {
        // Get the old value
        m_oldOrder = area.activationOrder();
    }

    ~ActivationOrderState()
    {
        // Restore the old value
        m_area.setActivationOrder( m_oldOrder );
    }

private:
    QMdiArea& m_area;
    QMdiArea::WindowOrder m_oldOrder;
};
```

This object is then used like this

```
{
    ActivationOrderState state(*mdiArea); // saves the state
    mdiArea->setActivationOrder( QMdiArea::StackingOrder ); // set the new state

    // do other things here...

} // end of scope, destructor is called and state is restored again
```

to be sure that no other user misuses this code by allocating it on the free store/heap instead of on the local scope, you can delete the operator new:

```
class ActivationOrderState
{
public:
    ActivationOrderState(QMdiArea& area)
        : m_area(area)
    {
        // Get the old value
        m_oldOrder = area.activationOrder();
    }

    ~ActivationOrderState()
    {
        // Restore the old value
        m_area.setActivationOrder( m_oldOrder );
    }

    // Remove the possibility to create this object on the free store.
    template<typename... Args> void* operator new(std::size_t,Args...) = delete;

private:
    QMdiArea& m_area;
    QMdiArea::WindowOrder m_oldOrder;
};
```

See also 
[Using RAII to raise thread priority temporarily](http://www.moderncplusplus.com/using-raii-to-raise-the-current-thread-priority-temporarily/)

Comment: that 'no free store allocation' can be done as a one-liner: `template<typename... Args> void* operator new(std::size_t,Args...) = delete;`

Comment: @sp2danny good comment, I edited the answer with delete instead to get a cleaner code.